# Firefox directory listing file size in Megabyte

Tags: firefox

I have local folder of videos, Firefox listing all of them with Title, Size and Time,

Size of the files are showing up in KB which are not human readable unless you are Maths-Guru.

Is there a way to show file size in Megabytes, Can we change that in `about:config` ?

[image: Firefox Directory listing]

Answer (score 1):

This is not possible in Firefox. There is no such option in configuration settings. You may use a third party software to display file sizes in different units.

Comment: Any official statement made by mozilla on this ?

Comment: @RahulVSharma On such a minor issue I doubt it the fact there isn’t a configuration option says everything you need to know